# Rotate video player to landscape mode in iOS 7

Tags: ios, youtube, rotation, video-player

I am playing some video from youtube embedded in web view, I need the video player to rotate horizontally or vertically but I haven't been able to do it. I need specifically the video player to rotate, not the view since the application works in portrait mode. Any help will me greatly appreciated. [image: ios app config]
[image: Video player screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plist file, you should check all orientations your application will support.
That means, you should check Landscape Left and Landscape Right too.

Them for each ViewController you don't want to rotate, you need to implement these methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: It works if the view is being displayed modally, which works perfectly